# Android kernel extracting headers

Tags: android, kernel

I downloaded the source code `common-android11-5.4` for Andreoid 5.4 and tried to extract the hearers from it, using make `headers_install` as per the linux native kernel method, but it didn't work and reported an error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'headers_install'.  Stop.
```

Any experts guide a way to extract the headers file from Andreoid for compilation of other programs.

Thanks!